# Python script using regex (re) to remove extra newlines

Tags: python, regex

I have a tab-delimited text file that may have some values containing newlines, like this:

```
        col1    col2    col3

row1    val1    "Some text
containing newlines. Yup, possibly
more than one..."        val3
row2    val4    "val5"    val6
```

Note:

- Text value that would contain newlines is **guaranteed** to be enclosed in double quotes initially
- Number of rows or columns may be different.
- Any value may be text or may be a number, **may contain newlines** and **may not**

I am trying to write a small Python script using `re` in order to:

- get rid of **extra newlines** (but preserve the original ones, i.e. at the end of each row)
- enclose every single value in double quotes

It would be great to have it in a form like that:

```
def normalize_format(data, delimiter = '\t'):
    data = re.sub(_DESIRED_REGEX_, r'"\1"', data)
    return data
```

where `data` is the whole file contents as a single string and `_DESIRED_REGEX_` is the one I would like to have figured out

Usage of `re` is not mandatory, but short and elegant solution is appreciated :)

Comment: By "extra newlines", you mean the newlines within a value, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling extra newlines (carriage returns) in csv files parsed with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146564/handling-extra-newlines-carriage-returns-in-csv-files-parsed-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead:

```
import csv
with open("mycsv.csv", "rb") as infile, open("newcsv.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t")
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    # Now you can remove all the newlines within fields
    # and write them back to a new CSV file:

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow([field.replace("\n", " ") for field in row])
```