# Pandas: how to read csv with multiple lines on the same cell?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a `csv` that I am not able to read using `read_csv`
Opening the `csv` with sublime text shows something like:

```
col1,col2,col3
text,2,3
more text,3,4
HELLO

THIS IS FUN
,3,4
```

As you can see, the text `HELLO THIS IS FUN` takes three lines, and `pd.read_csv` is confused as it thinks these are three new observations. How can I parse that correctly in Pandas?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting problem.  I we don't treat the new lines as new observations, how do we know if on "text, 2, 3" that it really should be "text, 2, 3 more text"?  I am not sure you can properly format this with this input.

Comment: yeah, that's a problem here... maybe by forcing the parser to find exactly three columns?

Comment: I would open it in pure python and replace all whitespaces with e.g one underscore. You can identify the lines by the absence of commas within the newline characters. Is this behavior consistent with the uppercase letters ?

Comment: thanks @moritz. good idea. can you please write some pseudo code to do that?

Comment: what ? You have 3k+ reputation. I think you can do it on your own. Are you familiar with the "with open('file', 'r') as f: for line in f: do something " syntax ?

Comment: i want to give you the opportunity to shine!!! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling extra newlines (carriage returns) in csv files parsed with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146564/handling-extra-newlines-carriage-returns-in-csv-files-parsed-with-python)

Comment: guys stop with finding duplicates that are not duplicates...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll have to preprocess the data manually:

```
with open('data.csv','r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
processed = []
cum_c = 0
buffer = ''
for line in lines:
    buffer += line # Append the current line to a buffer
    c = buffer.count(',')
    if cum_c == 2:
        processed.append(line)
        buffer = ''
    elif cum_c > 2:
        raise # This should never happen
```

This assumes that your data only contains unwanted newlines, e.g. if you had data with say, 3 elements in one row, 2 elements in the next, then the next row should either be blank or contain only 1 element. If it has 2 or more, i.e. it's missing a necessary newline, then an error is thrown. You can accommodate this case if necessary with a minor modification.

Actually, it might be more efficient to remove newlines instead, but it shouldn't matter unless you have a *lot* of data.